# Unity StartCoroutine MoveNext and mapper?

Tags: c#, mrtk

I have just jumped to Unity and I am doing some experiments to retrive data from an API

Below you can see the test code could you please help me to understand if i am the right way or not please?, because probably i am missing the mapper isn't it ?

Thanks in advance.

```
  void Start()
    {    
        comments= StartCoroutine(this.GetComments("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"));
        Debug.Log(comments);
    }

   private IEnumerator Comments GetComments(string url) {

        List<Comments> returnComments = new List<Comments>();

        UnityWebRequest comments = UnityWebRequest.Get(url)
        comments.SendWebRequest();

        while (comments.MoveNext())
        {
            var comment = comments.Current;                    
            returnItems.Add(comment);
        }

        return returnComments;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yield the SendWebRequest function.

```
yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
```

Access the data through the download handler.

```
var dataString = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
```

Full sample code in the docs [UnityWebRequest.Get](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html)